# Get variable value from the response of an HTTP Sampler to Beanshell PostProcessor

Tags: javascript, jmeter

In HTTP Sampler,response I have a javascript variable

```
int a=1;
```

I want to get the value of this 'a' in BeanShell Post Processor, How do I get it in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting in JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would suggest going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead. The relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
def text = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info('Response text is' + text)
def match = text =~ /int a=(\d+)/
if (match.find()) {
    def value = match.group(1)
    log.info('------------------')
    log.info('a value=' + value) 
    vars.put('a', value) 
}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy Extract Data From Response]

References:

- [Groovy: Regular expression operators](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can add Regular Expression Extractor as a Post Processor

```
Regular Expression: int a=(\w+);
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

For Beanshell (or better JSR 223) Post processor you will have to "work" to get the regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
String stringToSearch=prev.getResponseDataAsString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("int a=(\\w+)");   
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
if (m.find()){
  vars.put("a", m.group(1));
}
```

In this script I'm adding the value to variable a, which later can be called `${a}`