# how to write data to csv in jmeter using JSR Post processor

Tags: javascript, python

I am using JMeter v4.0 and I need to get data from the responses of the test using  JSR223 Post processor and How do I store this extracted data to a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 portions to the question posted

1. Extracting data from the response
2. Storing the extracted value in CSV file

The following code helps for resolving both the above questions. This code needs to be tweaked for your requirement (in terms of regex, file writing options etc.). But the basic skeleton is given

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.FileWriter;

//This helps in fetching the response of the request
String response=prev.getResponseDataAsString();

//Modify regex as necessary
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("responseValue=(\\w+);");   
Matcher myMatch = myPattern.matcher(response);

if (myMatch.find()){
  //This is solely to check the value extracted in Debug Sampler 
  //since myMatch.group(#) can be used directly in this code to write to file
  vars.put("extractedValue", myMatch.group(1));

  //File write operations
  String fileName = "example.csv";
  File file = new File(fileName);

  //Remove true for overwriting the file
  FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

  //Values to be written may include additional groups. Remember to separate them with comma
  String valueToWriteInFile = myMatch.group(1)+",othervalues";
  fileWriter.append(valueToWriteInFile);
  fileWriter.append("\n");

  //File needs to be properly closed to see the values written by JMeter on the file. 
  //Else, the file will only be created without any values
  fileWriter.close();
}
```

Reference Links used to build the above code:

1. [Extract Response using JSR223 Sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276576/get-variable-value-from-the-response-of-an-http-sampler-to-beanshell-postprocess)
2. [File Writing Options](https://dzone.com/articles/saving-data-to-csv-files-with-java-through-jmeter)

P.S. Use the JSR223 post-processor as a child for the request for which the above functions need to be carried out.